# How to auto run a macro if any of the cell value changes in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to auto run a macro based on the change of cell value to True. However, the macro is not running. Can someone help?
Below the code I am using ("send_auto_mail" is the cell reference where value changes on a specific time):

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Set Target = Range("send_auto_mail") 

If Target.Value = TRUE Then
    Call Sendmails
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: a) Target is the cell or cells that have changed. You shouldn't be Setting it to another range.  b) Worksheet_Change doesn't work on changes to a cell's formula result. Only when a cell's value changes. c) This is VBA not VB.Net.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I am not a technical guy, i am a finance guy and know bit of programming so write some macros. Am not sure I fully understand your suggestion. Instead of setting target value should I use following: If Range("name").value = true

Comment: Please explain **exactly** how Range("send_auto_mail") gets changed to True.

Comment: as you said, it contains a formula, linked to time. If time hits say 430pm, then the cell value changes to true.

Comment: Are you a professional programmer? Can you develop an excel model for our portfolio companies based on templates we will provide? I have already written a set of macros to achieve reporting? Can I reach you on some phone number please if you are based in India?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO. First of all, if you want to activate this only when a cell changes value, you need to put your code in event `Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()`

> **[Worksheet.Calculate Event (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.calculate(even))**

About your code, just check the named range you have. If it's `True` then activate your macro. So something like this should work for you (may need an adaptation):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

If Range("send_auto_mail") = True Then Call Sendmails

End Sub
```

Hope you can adapt this to your needs. Make sure you put this code in the right worksheet!

Comment: This worked!!! Phenomenal!! Thanks a million!! I had put the code in a separate module, now brought into the sheet making it private and it worked seamlessly.